# In Forest of the Dead, why did the Doctor Moon appear malevolent to the saved citizens?

Tags: doctor-who

In S04E09 of Doctor Who, *Forest of the Dead*, the [Doctor Moon](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Doctor_Moon), the antimalware guardian   of the computer running [The Library](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Library), saves 4,022 of its visitors from the [Vashta Nerada](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Vashta_Nerada) by teleporting them out and saving them into its hard drive, where they lived virtual lives, albeit drastically condensed because of the hard drive's limited space. One of those saved in this way was Donna Noble.

However, there seems to be no explanation given for why: *a)* the Doctor Moon continued to appear to Donna in her virtual life in order to ensure that she remained unaware of where she was, and *b)* why the Doctor Moon appears malevolent to her.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Doctor Moon's job was to keep people happy in the virtual world, and therefore unaware that they are in a virtual world.

He continues to appear specifically at times that Donna is questioning her reality, particularly in the beginning of her integration. Afterwards he doesn't monitor her as closely.

As to whether the Doctor Moon appears malevolent to her, I didn't really see that as the case most of the time. But if you thought so, the connection is most likely that he's specifically trying to alter her reality and she's resisting that. It doesn't matter that his intentions are good. She doesn't know why, the source of being brainwashed into accepting a virtual reality would be sinister for almost anyone. Some part of her subconscious knows.

Comment: Also, Dr Moon didn't do the saving, CAL did

Comment: @Adeptus Yes. It was CAL, the Doctor Moon was there to help her and handle integration into the system--including CAL. It's difficult to know where CAL began and the Doctor Moon started as far as systems were concerned. He managed everything for her, and it was his programing that helped her create a place for all the people.

Comment: In that respect, Doctor Moon has exactly the same role as the Agents in the Matrix. People who are aware of their reality's true nature are a danger for the whole system, so the "resistance" has to be kept to the minimum. And I think Doctor Moon rather appears sinister to the viewers, not in-universe, mostly because he tries to keep the doctor away from CAL when he first appears (which is in fact just a normal function of a firewall protecting against external intrusion).

Comment: Though the doctor moon is said to have been with virus or some other problem because CAL has saved too many people and there is no enough space in the drive. so there were a lot of glitches and doctor moon did his best in keeping everything under control.